# How do you write column data in rocksDB in java?

Tags: java, rocksdb, rocksdb-java

How do you write data in column format in rocksdb.

Example of columns can be `Id, state, URL, fieldNames, query`;

I should be able to read all data giving `Id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RocksDB is a key value store, so it doesn't have the concept of columns. What you can do, is to store a serialized object as value, which in your example would contain e.g. state, url, fieldnames and query, and use the id as key.